# Plotting 3D scatter plot on top of map or image

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter3d

I am trying to visualize some drone flights I did, measuring the signal strength.
For this I want to use 3D scatter plots in matplotlib.
Now it would be cool if I could use a map of the area as a base of the plot.
For the map I would simply use Google Maps static api, that's no problem.
Is this in any way possible, to add this to a 3D plot?
I was thinking if plot_surface or imshow could work, but I had no success.

So in summary is it possible to integrate a image on the xy plane?

Here is a picture of how I imagine it to look.

[image: scatter plot with map]

Comment: If it is an image, you can [display it on the z-axis pane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37480529/8881141)

Comment: Cool, that works thanks!
Don't know how I missed that before...
New here, so how can I give you credit for answering, if its only a comment?

Comment: Give the user who created this answer credit with an upvote if you have sufficient reputation points.

Comment: Allright, will do that when my reputation is high enough, thanks :)